# How can I get email alerts of conferences, summer schools and workshops in statistical physics?

Tags: conference, workshop, summer-school

To the statistical physics community: I am a PhD student in theoretical statistical physics. I want to be up-to-date with my field. How can I get newsletter/ email alerts/ updates of summer schools, seminars, workshops and conferences in statistical physics research? I want ideally around Europe.

I use twitter but I was wondering if there is any better way?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP can do the unavoidable leg-work for himself. The leg-work might be useful if he is looking for a job in the future, in any event.

Answer (score 0):

Ask around your department. Surely there is a professional journal/magazine, titled e.g. The Theoretical Physicist, that has these blue pages listing conferences of possible interest to members of the profession ?

Every university has a theoretical physics school and all will have seminars. I suppose you need to select those universities whose Schools of Theoretical Physics do research in your area. Create a mailing list of the contact emails for Coordinator of Seminars in each of those Schools. Then send an email to this group asking to be added to their mailing list for upcoming events.

In practice you may only be interested in going to seminars within reasonable travel distance, unless the quality of the seminars is very high/prestigious. That might cull the herd a bit for you !